# What do you call the connector type which is soldered on PCB and it holds cables by pressing on them by screws?

Tags: connector, identification

Here is a picture of two of them:

[image]

I searched for these connectors in [Digikey](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en) and [Farnell](http://uk.farnell.com/connectors) for an hour, but couldn't find anything similar. Can you please name these connectors for me and/or give a link to their subcategory in one of these part seller websites?

Comment: terminal blocks, screw terminal blocks http://www.pololu.com/catalog/category/117

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Screw terminal blocks
Also, Euro style connectors.